# After Completing progress in bar, URL is not being generated even though File is Uploaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, asynchronous, firebase-storage

After file is uploaded and progress bar completes till 100 , URL isn't generated but if I remove code of progress, URL is generated

```
const handleChange = async (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    //Path of the file.
    const storageRef = storage.ref("files/");
    const fileRef = storageRef.child(file.name);
    //Upload files in firebase storage.
    const time= await fileRef.put(file).on(
      "state_changed",
      (snapshot) => {
        const progress = Math.round(
          (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
        );
        setprogress(progress);
      }
    )
    //URL being generated
    setUrl(await fileRef.getDownloadURL());
    storage.refFromURL(url);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I overridden the functions of the `on` callback, and I'm generating the URL in the `complete` event, this behaviour is explained in more detail in this [Firebase storage document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#monitor_upload_progress)

```js
var storage = firebase.storage().ref("files/").child(file.name);

//upload file
var upload = storage.put(file);

//update progress bar
upload.on(
    "state_changed",
    function progress(snapshot) {
        var percentage = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
        setprogress(percentage);
    },

    function error() {
        alert("error uploading file");
    },

    function complete() {
        // generate URL
        storage
            .getDownloadURL()
            .then(function(url) {
                console.log(url);
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log("error encountered");
            });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you soo much it worked out , i thought how those functions were getting called that is why i didnt use them, 
small change i made in that , setprogress (progress ) changed to setprogress (percentage ) . Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

As we had callback for setState in the class component for React, you have to do something like that

```
setUrl(await fileRef.getDownloadURL());
```

useEffect to watch that state change

```
useEffect(() => {
   storage.refFromURL(YOUR_URL_STATE);
}, [YOUR_URL_STATE]);
```